# Übersetzung von »It’s not a question of if, it’s a question of when«

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

Wenn man versucht, dramatisch zu klingen, sagt man oft

> It’s not a question of if, it’s a question of when.

auf Englisch – besonders in Filmen.

Wie könnte man diesen Ausdruck übersetzen? Es ist ja schwierig, weil das deutsche Wort *wenn* zwei englische Bedeutungen hat, nämlich *when* und *if.* 
Könnte man Folgendes sagen?

> Es ist nicht eine Frage von *wenn,* sondern eine Frage von *wann.*

Irgendwie klingt das falsch. Vielleicht sollte es bestimmte Artikel geben: »von dem Wenn/Wann«.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Die Frage ist nicht „ob”, sondern „wann“.

Es geht dabei ja darum, zu sagen, dass etwas auf jeden Fall passiert. Das ist eine mögliche Antwort auf *ob,* aber nicht auf *falls* oder *wenn.*

Answer (score 8):

Wie bei Sprichwörtern üblich gibt es keine exakten Übersetzungen, ich denke diese sind am nächsten dran:

> Die Frage ist nicht ob, sondern wann
>
> Es ist nur eine Frage der Zeit

Comment: +1 for *Es ist nur eine Frage der Zeit* – most idiomatic in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Es ist auch möglich (und meiner Wahrnehmung nach nicht völlig ungeläufig), *wann* und *ob* zu substantivieren, allerdings im Genitiv:

> Es ist nicht eine Frage des Obs, sondern des Wanns.

Oder auch (meines Erachtens etwas weniger holprig):

> Es ist keine Frage des Obs, sondern nur des Wanns.

Comment: Auch wenn das möglich ist, habe ich es noch nie gehört. Trotzdem +1 für eine Alternative.

Comment: Anekdotisch: ich kenne mehrere Leute, die das so verwenden. Sowas ist auch häufig regional.